# How to select the elements of a Pandas DataFrame given a Boolean mask?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering wether, given a boolean mask, there is a way to retreive all the elements of a DataFrame positioned in correspondance of the *True* values in the mask.

In my case I have a DataFrame containing the values of a certain dataset, for example let's take the following :

```
l = [[5, 3, 1], 
     [0, 3, 1], 
     [7, 3, 0], 
     [8, 5, 23], 
     [40, 4, 30],
     [2, 6, 13]]
df_true = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['1', '2', '3'])
df_true
```

Then I randomly replace some of the values with 'np.nan' as follows:

```
l2 = [[5, 3, np.nan], 
     [np.nan, 3, 1], 
     [7, np.nan, 0], 
     [np.nan, 5, 23], 
     [40, 4, np.nan],
     [2, np.nan, 13]]
df_nan= pd.DataFrame(l2, columns=['1', '2', '3'])
df_nan
```

Let's say that after applying some imputation algorithm I obtained as a result:

```
l3 = [[5, 3, 1], 
     [2, 3, 1], 
     [7, 8, 0], 
     [8, 5, 23], 
     [40, 4, 25],
     [2, 6, 13]]
df_imp= pd.DataFrame(l3, columns=['1', '2', '3'])
df_imp
```

Now I would like to create two lists (or arrays), one containing the *imputed* values and the other one the *true* values in order to compare them. To do so I first created a mask `m = df_nan.isnull()` which has value *True* in correspondance of the cells containing the imputed values. By applying the mask as `df_imp[m]` I obtain:

```
     1       2       3
0   NaN     NaN     1.0
1   2.0     NaN     NaN
2   NaN     8.0     NaN
3   8.0     NaN     NaN
4   NaN     NaN     25.0
5   NaN     6.0     NaN
```

Is there a way to get instead only the values without also the *Nan*, and put them into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) to return a numpy representation of the DataFrame then use [`numpy.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) and keep other values.

```
import numpy as np
arr = df.values
res = arr[~np.isnan(arr)]
print(res)
# [1. 2. 8. 8. 25. 6.]
```